# java методы и их параметры - влияние передачи через аргументы больших данных на производительность

Tags: java, android

Как влияет на быстродействие программы то, что я передаю от метода к методу параметр, имеющий большой объем данных. К примеру переменную типа BufferedReader, в которой содержится контент объемом 3 мегабайта?

Или на скорость работы программы это не влияет?

Comment: Нет, передаю переменную и использую ее в методе, ничего необычного. Спасибо за комментарий)

Comment: Интересная статья, узнал новое - спасибо)

Comment: @Nofate, пусть андроид будет. Всё ж под него в основном на java пишут, и многие гуглят вопросы по яве через ключевик андроид, т.к. выдача по яве плоха. Совсем.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В *java* объекты всегда передаются только по ссылке (за исключением примитивов, т.е. всегда будет прокидываться лишь ссылка объект, передаваемый параметром в метод, которая занимает всего `4 байта`, хотя на самом деле зависит от разрядности системы: на *32-разрядной* - `4 байта`, на *64-разрядной* - `8 байт`). Таким образом, это абсолютно не критично, по крайней мере, необходимо выполнить просто неимоверное количество передач параметров по ссылке, чтобы это возымело серьезные последствия на современных машинах.

Если, конечно, вы не копируете это объект прямо в теле метода (правда зачем?).

Правда, стоит быть аккуратным при `autoboxing`'е примитивов при передаче в качестве параметров в функцию и при работе с контейнерами, подробнее можете прочитать [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/104231/).

Comment: Все же обычно говорят, что все объекты передаются по значению, в том числе и указатели на объект - по значению)

Comment: @PavelParshin Хм, мне всегда казалось, что под "передать объект по значению" подразумевается создать копию объекта (т.е. в терминах `java` посредством `new`), а вот "передать указатель на объект по значению" - совсем другое дело, ведь тогда мы копируем лишь указатель, а не сам объект)